# Validate and encode urls containing unicode characters in Java

Tags: java, validation, url

I am working on an application in which we need to validate URLs , check if it started with http ( if not, prepend 'http') and finally encode them. My problem is urls we receive can contain all types of things - invalid / valid but not starting with http / already encoded / valid but containing spaces or unicode characters. 
Currently I am using URLValidator class, but it does not validate spaces or unicode chars. Following is my code:

```
if (url != null && !url.trim().isEmpty()) {
url = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
if (!url.matches("^(https?)://.*$")) {
    url = "http" + url;
}
UrlValidator validator = new UrlValidator();
if (url.contains("(")) {
    if (validator.isValid(url.substring(0, url.indexOf("(")))) {
        return getEncodedSiteUrl(url);
    }
    return null;
}
if (validator.isValid(url)) {
    return getEncodedSiteUrl(url);
}
}
```

But this code filters out all valid urls that contain a space / unicode chars. I don't think I should use URLValidator looking at all the types of urls we get. Can anybody please help / guide me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.santhoshreddymandadi.com/java/best-url-and-email-validation-using.html) URL which has a method you may use.

```
public static boolean isURL(String url)
{
   if (url == null) {
     return false;
}
// Assigning the url format regular expression
String urlPattern = "^http(s{0,1})://[a-zA-Z0-9_/\\-\\.]+\\.([A-Za-z/]{2,5})[a-zA-Z0-9_/\\&\\?\\=\\-\\.\\~\\%]*";
return url.matches(urlPattern);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it does not solve my problem. It doesn't validate urls like -                                     "http://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Sport/Football/Premier League/Transfer News"

Comment: Even stackoverflow does not allow it. I guess due to spaces. :)

Comment: url having spaces shouldbe encoded before using them.

Comment: Yes. I tried encoding and then validating with the above regex. It doesn't pass.